# Generating multiple curves with geometry nodes from the same object without joining them

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a plane that I'm attempting to create a topology effect with. This plane has an array modifier stacked on top of a boolean modifier that intersects with a mountain/wave shape to create a "stepped" topology effect on the plane. Then, I turn this plane into a set of curves using a geometry modifier. The curves are generated, however Blender seems to think that each of the non-intersecting curves must be connected in some fashion, creating awkward straight lines across the mesh instead of rendering each curve independently. Note that the objects generated by the array (so, each "level" of the effect) are NOT connected; the curves on each individual plane are intra-connected.

[image: Contour effect]

How can I tell geometry nodes to create independent curves?

Geometry nodes:

[image: Geometry node setup]

Comment: Just add a [Decimate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html) modifier (set to *Planar*) before the *Geometry Nodes* modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though the Boolean operation has created internal edges on some faces.

The easiest way to lose those would be at some stage where your contour-mesh still has faces. You could use a *Decimate* modifier > Planar, or pass the still-filled shapes with their excess edges to GN, and get rid of them there, by deleting edges which are not boundaries:

[image]

(The *Delete Geometry* > Only Faces is not strictly necessary, just being clunky to be readable)

[image]